# Getting null from enzyme shallow renderer

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

In my create-react-app, I have setup tests with jest(preconfigured) and enzyme. Added the enzymetoJson serializer in package.json.

```
"jest": {
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
  }
```

But when I am asserting in dom, I'm getting bellow error.

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined**

Below is the code snippet.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar';


it('should render layout', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Navbar />);
    console.log(wrapper)
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
})

it('should have brand name Montrack', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<div><b>important</b></div>);
    console.log(wrapper)  // log - ShallowWrapper {}
    expect(wrapper.text()).to.equal('important');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Chai with enzyme. `to.equal` is Chai syntax. It is `toEqual` in enzyme.